# Is it possible for a common server with 1Gbps bandwidth sent 1M UDP packets per second?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, udp

I wrote a simple UDP packet sender like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
using namespace std;

char a[10];
int times = 100000;
struct sockaddr_in server;
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

void fun2()
{
    for(int i=0; i<times; i++){
        sendto(fd, a, 10, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if(argc > 1)
        times = atoi(argv[1]);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.102");

    struct timeval begin, end;
    gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);
    fun2();
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    double tu = double(1000000*(end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec) + (end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec)) / 1000000;
    cout << tu << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I run this sender on a common server(4 cores 8 threads, 8G mem, 1Gbps NIC), when the `times` set to 100K, the time usage is about 0.7 second, which means this sender could sent about 150K packets/s.
So I would like to know, which part of the system limits the sender? If I used multi-thread, is it able to send more? What's the limitation of multi-thread? And at last, is it possible to reach 1M packets/s?

Comment: Do the math on packet size.  **Be particular about the difference between bits and bytes**.  Your link is maxed already.  In fact, even 150k packets/s of 1024 payload bytes each is not possible without packet loss.  Perhaps some have been queued but not yet transmitted.

Comment: Yes you're right, there is something wrong with my code, I would fix them and then update the question.

Comment: I reduced the packet to 10 bytes size, and I used tcpdump to monitor the amount of packets sent, 100K packets still be sent in 1 second( when I end tcpdump, it shows more than 100K packets received by filter '), and time usage is still the same. I don't actually know what happen :(